# undefined in html, using inner html

Tags: javascript, html

so, i'm trying to do a table in HTML and my code is like this.

```
<script>
function addtable()
{
 var incr;
 incr += "<table id="nicetable"....
 more code
 incr += "</table>";
 document.getElementById("divfortable").innerHTML=incr;
}
</script>
<div id="divfortable"></div>
```

And it appeared undefined and the table on my webpage. I've tried even commenting all of my code and only inserting a word in my "incr" variable, and still appeared the undefined word. So i did only:

```
document.getElementById("divfortable").innerHTML="hi";
```

And all went fine. And i've realized that the problem was from the var incr. And i don't know how to solve this. And it's quite odd, cuz I always do this to do tables, but now it's appearing the undefined word on the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the double quotes in `incr`, by replacing `"` with `\"`. Javascript can use double quotes to represent the start and end of a string, but the quotes in `id="nicetable"` are interfering.

In addition, you should initialize your variable:

```
var incr = "";
```

As by default, `incr` will be set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var incr;
 incr += "<table id=\"nicetable\"...."
 more code
 incr += "</table>";
```

or

```
var incr;
 incr += '<table id="nicetable"....'
 more code
 incr += '</table>';
```

Comment: Also, the variable `incr` should be defined like so: `var incr = "";` to avoid a default string value of 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```
var incr;
```

Then `incr` has value undefined, then you try to append string on it, and it converts undefined to string and appends string on it.

Solution would be:

```
var incr = "<table id="nicetable"....
```

So you don't have undefined starting value of `incr`.

Comment: This is not incorrect, but his main issue lies with his quotations, check again. Also, to define a string variable without the "undefined" string do: `var incr = "";`